# Filtering Rails database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have created a database of researchers and the papers they have written in Rails.  I need to be able to filter it by author in such a way that information is drawn from the database onto a page in the persons name (for example if there is a researcher called Dr. A. Researcher, I need to be able to go to his page, and that page will be populated with papers that he/she has written automatically).  I have been working on this for a while now, and have gone round in circles so many times, Im not exactly sure what I am looking for (though I think its probably going to be AJAX based).  Filtering the database seems quite straightforward, but I cant seem to find any information about sending the results of that filter to a specific page.

As I say, Im not totally sure what Im looking for here, so someone may have had a similar issue that has already been answered.  If that is the case, I apologise.  Any help anyone has about this would be very gratefully received.

Cheers

Comment: Seems like you want to make a researcher#show page that has_many :papers, which you'll then iterate through on the view. What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you would just want to use the show action.

In your controllers/researchers.rb controller add

```
def show
  @reseacher = Reseacher.find(params[:id])
end
```

or possibly

```
def show
    @reseacher = Reseacher.find(params[:id], include: [:papers])
end
```

then in your views/show.html.erb view you can just add

```
<% @reseacher.papers.each do |p| %>
    <%= p.title %>
    <%= p.otherattribute %>
<% end %>
```

Also you will need to ensure your relationships are setup correctly in your model

in models/researcher.rb

add

```
has_many :papers
```

to the Researcher Class

and in models/papers.rb

add

```
belongs_to :researcher
```

to the Paper Class

localhost:3000/reseachers/1 where 1 is the id of the researcher should then return the papers for that researcher

Comment: Hey, Jon.  I will definitely give this a try tomorrow and let you know how it went.  Cheers, mate.  P

Comment: Hey, Jon

OK.  Ive tried your advice - getting a type conflict for some reason, saying that its expecting author (then a number in brackets) but getting string (then a number in brackets).  Would this be something to do with how I set up the table itself?

Comment: If you can provide the error report you are getting I might be able to help. All I can say from the above is that whatever view you are trying to load is that a string is being passed where an author object should be or thats what it sounds like.

Comment: OK I was expecting a little more than that, when do you receive this error. Is this when trying to load the show view? Also maybe you could  update your question to now include what you have added to your views, models and controllers

Comment: Jon.  OK, this is the error message

`Author(#85761170) expected, got String(#69251870)`.

Its telling me that there is something up in the publications controller, but I cant see what it is.  Im utterly stumped.  Any ideas?

Comment: All I can say from that is that it looks like you are using the Author object somewhere instead of the Author.id perhaps but this is just a guess really without seeing the code. Can you post the publication controller to your original question then?

Comment: It is indeed when I try to load the show view, yes.  Another error I get is this one `SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: publications.author_id: SELECT "publications".* FROM "publications"  WHERE "publications"."author_id" = 1`  Both seem to suggest that a string rather than an object is being passed I think.  Again, I get this error when trying to update the show view.  I will update my question.

Comment: OK.  Tried to post the publication controller to the question, but it was too long.....

Comment: hmm add it to pastepin.com and post the url here?

Comment: OK.  Ive put it on pastebin.com.  The url is [http://pastebin.com/3JTpbkz4.  Cheers

Comment: OK.  Ive got the first error sorted (not quite sure how, but Im not getting it coming up now). Still getting this one though.  `SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: publications.author_id: SELECT "publications".* FROM "publications"  WHERE "publications"."author_id" = 1 `  When I try to perform the show action on the author.  Nothing Im trying will shift it.  Do I need to add an index, through a migration?

Comment: The piece of code that it doesnt seem to like is in this, in the author show view  `<% @author.publications.each do |p| %>
<%= p.title %>
<% end %>`

Comment: And you definitely have an author_id field in your publications model?

Comment: I think the problem is that I dont have an id field - rails uses it as a primary field, right?  So, to save messing about with primary keys, Im just going to delete the authorid field (no underscore) and just create an id field.  Seems like the easiest solution all round, right?

Comment: THink I'll just rename it with a migration, actually.  Thanks for your help, Jon - I appreciate it.  :-)

Comment: OK.  Thats done the trick.  I will mark this post as solved - cheers for all your help.  :-)